# Convertir correctamente un dato de tiempo en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

Tengo un string que almacena una medida de tiempo pero al querer convertirla a datetime me pasa lo siguiente:

String = 0:48:24
DateTime = 11:11:2020 12:48:24

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(total);
```

Cómo puedo obtener el datetime con el formato correcto?

Nota: Quiero realizar la transformación para así saber si el tiempo que tengo en String es menor a 2:00:00 hrs, es por esto que quiero convertirlo a DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo el objeto `DateTime` puedes usar  su propiedad `Hour`:

```
String s = "0:48:24";
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(s);

if(d.Hour < 2){
  // hay menos de dos horas
}
```

Comment: Pero en este caso no afecta que al convertirlo me tire el 12:48:24 para conseguir la hora?

Comment: No porque esa es la representación en formato de 12 horas. Internamente la propiedad `Hour` es 0 porque es la media noche.

Comment: Oh, pensé que afectaba en algo. Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar!

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que vas a utilizar es sólo horas, tal vez te convenga usar la clase [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan), que es más acorde.

Sería algo así:

```
String time = "0:48:24";

if(TimeSpan.Parse(time).Hours < 2){
  // hay menos de dos horas
}
```

Suerte!